# iOS 8 UITableViewCell with UIImageView dynamic height

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

while trying to apply iOS8 dynamic height to my custom UITableViewCell, which should expand and keep it aspect ratio, the simulator a throwing the bellow warning.

If i remove the suggested constrain, which is the aspect ratio of the UIImageView, i lose the image aspect ratio and the image is stretched.

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc8490680 UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.width == 1.73571*UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.height>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc991e100 UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00.topMargin + 43>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc991e150 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.trailing + 4>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc991e1f0 UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00.leadingMargin + 57>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc991e270 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00.bottomMargin == UIImageView:0x7fccc8490560.bottom - 4>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc849ac20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00(414)]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fccc84b19a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fccc848cc00(249)]>
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Answer (score 1):

i just found the solution to the above problem.

lowering the priority of the aspect ration constrain to 750 seems to fix this problem